# Write to a file in the current directory

Tags: c

I am required to run my compiled program using my account in university's HPCC center. My program should output the results in a text file, so I am using `fopen` function:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("Users/Tiff/Documents/output.txt", "w+");
```

In my computer, I can simply specify the entire path but in HPCC I don't know my account's path on HPCC's main cluster. How do I make my program output the result in the same directory on my HPCC account without having to know the full path?

Comment: By not using absolute paths. By default the working directory is the current directory. Just use the filename

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the following code:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("output.txt", "w+");
```

The file "output.txt" would be in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the name of the .txt file, it will automatically output to the current working directory.

In your case: `FILE *fp = fopen("output.txt", "w+");`